# Regex expression for a string pattern

Tags: regex

Regex newbie here. I need to create a regex expression that will support following strings:

```
<optional constant string 1><string 2><space><string 3>
```

Here constant string 1 is: `ad_`

Ex (allowed patterns).

`[1]`
`ad_xyz.qwe.sty blah blah...`
string 1: ad_
string 2: xyz.qwe.sty
string 3: blah blah... (free text)

`[2]`
`abc blah ...`
string 1: (absent)
string 2: abc
string 3: blah ... (free text)

`[3]`
`sdf.pqr blah blah blah...`
string 1: (absent)
string 2: sdf.pqr
string 3: blah blah blah... (free text)

Here is what I'm doing:

`(?:[ad_]{0,1})?\-[a-zA-Z.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Now this detects only first pattern. Though I have mentioned `{0,1}`, still `string 1` is mandatory.

Comment: `[ad_]` matches one of `a`, `d`, or `_`. If you want to match the whole string it’d be `ad_`; `(?:ad_)?` matches `ad_` zero or one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex for an optional match in first group:

```
^(ad_)?(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)\s*(.*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Y1EQQ/1)

In your regex `[...]` makes it [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) where only one character out of several character matches at a time so `[ad_]` match any one of `a` or `d` or `_`

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use this regex string:

```
^(ad_)?(\S*)\s(.*)
```